# Storage 100% full

Tags: filesystem

I don't have much experience in system administration. I have installed a Mastodon instance on a VPS running Ubuntu 20.04. After ten days the server has been completely filled, which seems very rare to me. How can 38Gb be filled?

If I do a `df -h`, I get this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            949M     0  949M   0% /dev
tmpfs           194M  860K  193M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        38G   36G     0 100% /
tmpfs           968M   28K  968M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           968M     0  968M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15      253M  138K  252M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           194M     0  194M   0% /run/user/0
```

As can be seen, the file system mounted on /dev/sda1 is completely full.

There must be something that takes up a lot of space, how can I find it?
How can I find a directory that takes up a lot of space?

`du -h` doesn't work for me because it starts printing thousands of lines and doesn't stop.

I would appreciate any hint or help.

**[EDIT] I don't want to delete the question even though it's been tagged as a duplicate because the linked question doesn't have the `du -h --max-depth=1` command among its answers, which for me has been crucial.**

Comment: try `du -h --max-depth=1` and proceed with the investigation based on the results. Perhaps some log files are becoming large in `/var/log`.

Comment: Yes! it works! With this command I have been delimiting the large directory and I now know where the problem is. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Duplicate questions are not deleted. And the command you mentioned are not among the answers here too.

Comment: My fault. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a better and interactive overview you can use [ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/scr).

Start count from current dir: `ncdu -x`

Start count from custom dir: `ncdu -x /some/dir`

(`-x` parameter is for "Do not cross filesystem boundaries")

Answer (score 1):

As Doug said in the comments, with `du -h --max-depth=1` I can delimiting the large directory.

Comment: You could do `sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean`

Comment: There is also a program called [BleachBit](https://www.bleachbit.org/download/linux). This is a system cleaner used to cleanup nd optimise your system.